# Screenshots are broken in extent reports selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java, extentreports

I want to add screenshots to extent reports so I took screenshot, stored them locally and then attached them to the report

I wanted to see the attached screenshot in the report but it is broken.

Here is the code that I used after opening a website

```
 File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String path = "H:\\Screenshots/sss.png";
    try {
        FileHandler.copy(screenshot, new File(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }test=extent.createTest("Opened huntington");
          test.log(Status.PASS,"1st log passed");
    test.addScreenCaptureFromPath("H:\\Screenshots\\sss.png");
    test.fail("details", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("H:\\Screenshots\\sss.png").build());
```

Answer (score 0):

The file path "H:\Screenshots/sss.png" is not correct because it uses a mix of backslashes and forward slashes, use either forward slashes (/) or double backslashes () as the path separator
use one from below

```
 String filePath = "H:/Screenshots/sss.png";
 String filePath = "H:\\Screenshots\\sss.png";
```

Comment: I was using the forward slash to create and save the image with the name as sss.png.